# Scheduling Timeouts in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, timeout

I have a bunch of sockets I read and write asynchronously. I want to execute code in case the remote peer does not react within a given time. I do not want a [`Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) objects as each of those runs in a different thread. Also, running a [`scheduler`](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler) in a separate thread that handles the timeouts seems infeasible due to `scheduler` not being thread-safe.

How can I schedule lots of timeouts efficiently?

Comment: How about http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html ?

Comment: @RestRisiko Could you elaborate? I'm probably missing something; I can't find any mention of timeouts in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Twisted Matrix](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: `callLater` seems to be the function I need, and it's even cancel-able! On the other hand, twisted seems quite complex and heavy, and I'd prefer a more light-weight solution (preferably, pure Python)

Comment: @phihag: You can "prefer" something "light-weight".  But I doubt such a thing exists.  What you're asking for isn't simple.